# Color text in select doesn't work on chrome

Tags: css, select

I'm trying to change the color of a select qith jquery like :

```
$('select').css('color', '#BD0926') ;
```

This code works with firefox, but not with chrome.. any ideas ?

Comment: Should work - could you be more specific? What is the element, maybe there is some syntax missing. An exact jsfiddle would be great

Comment: Works perfectly in Chrome 32.0: http://jsfiddle.net/dratir/zLbrC/ Check the console of the chrome developer tools for any error messages.

Comment: this should work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls like `checkbox`, `radio`, `select` and etc using a platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme. You can reset it by using [`-webkit-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance). But this property:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```